# Any comment service for flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a comment service on flutter without any server.
I'm planning to use "Utterances" for the comment system.
[Utterances uses the github issue system.]

So, I want to know how can I get the github issues by flutter.
Or another way to make a comment system on flutter without server.

I found a flutter package for using github, however it seems not possible to use it for get github issues. https://pub.dev/packages/github

Comment: So you will use Github as a backend/db?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry to ask a strange question. I thought that Utterances uses its own server for the comment service. Do you know how to create a comment system with GitHub or other free servers without usage limitations?